# Connecting Laravel to GAE Cloud SQL Database with PostgreSQL

Tags: laravel, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am deploying a new application to Google App Engine Flex environment. The app is powered by Laravel.

I am able to connect to the database on my local machine, however, I am unable to connect to the database once I deploy my application.

What information do I need to include in the app.yaml file to connect to the database? Do I require any other information in a different file?

`"message": "SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused\n\tIs the server running on host \"localhost\" (::1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\ncould not connect to server: Connection refused\n\tIs the server running on host \"localhost\" (127.0.0.1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432? (SQL: select * from \"users\" where \"email\" = mitchell@efficialtec.com and \"users\".\"deleted_at\" is null limit 1)",`

This is the contents of my .ENV file which allows me to connect locally

```
APP_ENV=development
APP_KEY=base64:B0G3Yr82fWO7xw8LrvcOC19DGUAEd32loJlPHCfP2sg=
APP_DEBUG=true

LOG_CHANNEL=stack


DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_POST=5432
DB_DATABASE=DATABASE
DB_USERNAME=USERNAME
DB_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
DB_SOCKET: "/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME"
```

This is the contents of my app.yaml file:

```
env: flex     # let app engine know we use flexible environment
service: SERVICENAME

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 2
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.8

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

skip_files:
  - .env #we want to skip this to make sure we don’t mess stuff up on the server

env_variables:
  # Put production environment variables here.
  APP_ENV: development
  APP_DEBUG : true # or false 
  APP_KEY: base64:B0G3Yr82fWO7xw8LrvcOC19DGUAEd32loJlPHCfP2sg=
  APP_LOG: daily
  APP_TIMEZONE: UTC #your timezone of choice


  # Replace USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE, and CONNECTION_NAME with the
  # values obtained when configuring your Cloud SQL instance.
  POSTGRES_USER: USERNAME
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
  POSTGRES_DSN: pgsql:dbname=bnsw;host=/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME"

  DB_HOST: localhost
  DB_DATABASE: DATABASE
  DB_USERNAME: USERNAME
  DB_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
  DB_SOCKET: "/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME" 

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: "CONNECTION_NAME"
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, I have been looking on Google for almost a week with no answers yet!

Answer (score 1):

By default, Laravel does not have DB_SOCKET under `pgsql` connection. 
Thus, in order to connect to cloud SQL connection from app engine, you env show look like :

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME
DB_DATABASE=DATABASE
DB_USERNAME=USERNAME
DB_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
```

Also please, don't include DB_PORT in the database env variables.